# Best way to get string representation of regex from regex literal

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

If I do this:

```
// note that \x1f is a control character
var regex = new RegExp("\x1f");

// prints "//"
console.log(regex.toString());
```

If I instead do this:

```
var regex = /\\x1f/;

// prints "/\\x1f/"
console.log(regex.toString());
```

I'd like to be able to get the first result (`//` - a string with a control character) from the second regular expression.  Is there a simple way to do this?  So far, I've only been able to do this with a disgusting `eval` hack:

```js
var regexValue = /\\x1f/.toString();

let escapedLiteral = regexValue

    // turn double backslashes (\\) into single backslashes (\), 
    .replace(/\\\\/g, '\\')
    
    // remove the opening and closing forward slashes (/).
    // this needs to be more intelligent - what if there are flags?
    .slice(1, -1);

// there could be an invalid regular expression string
try {
  regexValue = eval('new RegExp("' + escapedLiteral + '")').toString();
} catch (e) {
  regexValue = null;
}

// should print "//"
document.writeln(regexValue);
```

I'm doing some JavaScript source code parsing and this difference is making things challenging.

Comment: have you tried .source?

Comment: @YOU It looks like `.source` gives the same result as `.toString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `/\\x1f/` is not the same as `new RegExp("\x1f")`, it is rather `new RegExp("\\\\x1f")`.

Second, if you are doing the eval hack, you could just feed back the string representation of the regex to eval:

```
var x = /\x1f/;
console.log(eval(''+x));
```

Third, there are a lot of JavaScript parsing libraries out there, like esprima, espree or babylon. I recommend using one of them, or at least study their source code.

To quickly avoid the eval hack, you could do something like:

```
var literalStr = "/abc/gi";
var m = /^\/(.*)\/([a-z]*)$/.exec(literalStr);
var regexObj = m ? new RegExp(m[1], m[2]) : null;
console.log(regexObj);
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have realized that my two regular expression weren't the same.  That makes all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Or ...

```
/\x1f/.toString().replace(/\\x(..)/g, 
   function(a, b) {return a.replace("\\x" + b, String.fromCharCode(b));}
);
```